# How to Retrieve Library Addresses Linked to a Smart Contract on Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan, library, contract-verification, libraries

I've run into a situation where I need to identify the library addresses that a verified contract is linked to. I understand that during the contract verification process on Etherscan, one must provide the names and addresses of any linked libraries as these are deployed separately and their addresses are embedded in the contract's bytecode.

My question is twofold:

1. For a contract that has already been deployed and verified on Etherscan, is there a straightforward way to view the linked library addresses through the Etherscan interface? If so, could you guide me through the steps to locate this information?
2. In case the information isn't readily available on Etherscan, are there any recommended methods or tools to extract these addresses post-deployment, perhaps through the contract's bytecode or via a third-party tool?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have found in the openzeppelin forum:

> If you deployed the contract with Remix, the library was deployed automatically without your intervention. In the console, you should find an entry that says creation of library  pending..., followed by the transaction that deploys the library, where you will find its address. If you can't find this entry in the console, it will be very difficult to retrieve the library address.

> If you deployed the contract with Truffle migrations, this information is found in the corresponding build/contracts/.json file. In this file, there is a networks field that contains an entry for each network that you've ran your migrations on, indexed by network id. In the entry corresponding to the network you want to verify, you will find a field called links that contains name and address of each library that was used, and that you should input into Etherscan.

From this website: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-to-verify-a-contract-on-etherscan-bscscan-polygonscan/14225